# Customize asp.net mvc validation error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

I created this model class:

```
 public class test5
{
    [Required] //when title field empty send from client this is show this messae" The title field is required."
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int content { get; set; }
}
```

I want edit Required filed error message to custom message and when I use that validation like `[Required]` anywhere display that error message. how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keywoard ErrorMessage in dataanotation

```
public class test5
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation for a full guide and examples.

Comment: I know this way, but I want change Required default message in where required defined?

Comment: Have a look at this project here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780992/Asp-Net-MVC-Custom-Compare-Data-annotation-with-Cl

Comment: I want change default error message that micro-soft defined.